# How to type an algorithm in LaTeX without using packages?

Tags: tables, algorithms

For my paper in a Science journal, I face serious formatting errors if I use

```
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
```

My problem involves a caption, label (to refer to it), Inputs and Output.

I hope this can be done in a Table environment?

(I changed my actual entries in the paper as I hope to submit it by next week … I got stuck with typing out the algorithm in the paper.)

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  % \setstretch{1.2}
\footnotesize
\KwIn{ Parameters: $a=5$, $b = 2$, $c = 3$, .. \\ 
Initial conditions: $\big(x_1(t_0), y_1(t_0), z_1(t_0))\big)=(0.1,0.1,0.1)$, \\
Step size: $h = 0.01$,\\  }
 \While{True} {
    $k1a= a(z_2(t_0) - z_1(t_0))  -c z_3(t_0) $\\
    \textbf{Compute the solution}:\\
    $z_1 = z_1(t_0) + hk1a$ \\
    \textbf{Replace initial conditions}: \\
    $z_1(t_0) \gets z_1 $ \\
 }
 \KwOut{$z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$}
 \caption{Pseudocode for solving ...}
 \label{pseudocode}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: One possibility is to create a new document with the `standalone` documentclass, add the algorithm in there (without anything else), compile it, and add the result to your main document with `\includegraphics`.

Comment: I create a new document, just for the Algorithm, compile it, get a PDF and use the PDF for the Algorithm as a figure - The idea is very good in principle - I shall try it!

Comment: Marjin - I got the first Algorithm as LaTeX output, you suggested.. I have now problem in the numbering for the second Algorithm in the same paper.. Following your method, I got the output but it again says "Algorithm 1" only.. How do I increase the number from 1 to 2? In preamble, I have : \usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e} - How do I set counter for Algorithm? Thanks!

Comment: `\setcounter{algorithm}{1}` will probably work (insert this line in your standalone document before you start the algorithm).